# Find the area of the shaded region.

Tags: geometry, area

> [image]

Grade 10 question, but got confused on how to solve?

Comment: Welcome to MSE!! Can you please show us what you have tried?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Subtract the area of the triangle from the area of the trapezoid. Area of a trapezoid is:  $$\frac{(upper base+lowerbase)\cdot height}{2}$$
Area of a triangle is:
$$\frac{base\cdot height}{2}$$

Comment: Downvoted because the OP must show their own works on the problem and the answerer can only post hints if he/she refuses to do so, not full answers. This is a main policy to be followed on MSE as far as I can see. As an advice I would say to delete this answer and post a hint instead.

Comment: Well, thanks for explaining. I'm hearing this for the first time as I am used to seeing questions with no work effort answered fully. I will be more careful the next times.

Comment: I edited and made it a hint-style answer.

Comment: Great, retracted downvote.